# Accidentally override local branch by origin with pycharm

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have some branch name `X` I was working on. I committed my work locally (didn't push).

Then I noticed a bug and tried to compare my results to the ones in the remote.

I tried to checkout (through `pycharm`) to my remote branch. It says there are diffs and I should rebase, or override. I clicked override, thinking that rebase will push my changes, but I actually override my work on the local machine!

Is there anything I can do? I tried to look through `git log` and couldn't find a commit that has my work.

Even though I did commit my work before trying to checkout.

Thanks

EDIT: This was resolved (thanks god) using ctrl+z (and doing undo reload from disk).
I leave this still open since I don't have a clue what happen, so an explanation might help me or others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```sh
git reflog

# Search for your lost commit, and write down its hash code, then...

git checkout <LOST_COMMIT_HASH>
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't familiar with reflog